# how to display the web content which contain html code prolerly?

Tags: formatting

I wrote a simple article in my wordpress which contain some html code.

how to display the web content  prolerly?

[image]

The web to be displayed is not well formed ,how can i change it?
All the html code can't be displayed in my wordpress.
[image]

Comment: Look to the mighty codex and she will answer... [Display code in Wordpress Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a template and assign this template the page you are creating in admin.
Now in template get all content using page id. That's it.

Comment: please tell me in detail,step by step.